# How to call flow from one flow to another

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow called "A" and a flow called "B",In flow "B" i need to call a flow "A".How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [SubFlow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_subflow.htm) element to call another flow inside your master / parent flow

Here's a [reference article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/06/subflows-in-visual-workflow.html) from Salesforce on how to use sub flows.